# How to adjust time zones according to daylight saving in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

My application is hosted on Goddady server.Which is located on Indian time zone.

But my application is for AU client.And i need to figure out the AU time zone.

> > Means,in my application i am adding events in Google Calendar.But i have to add those events according to various Australian timezones and also according to daylight saving structure.

Is any body knows how can i figure out this on Goddady server?

For example,i want to add an event on 25-May,2013 at 4:00PM .And for that i want to adjust this according to one of any Australian time zone and daylight saving time.

Please let me know if anybody knows it.

I am working on ASP.NET application and SQL Server 2008 for it.

Thanks

Comment: You should use client side scripting to get the User's time, like in this digital clock example on my site: http://webinfocentral.com/

Answer (score 0):

well, this will be gouing to be little tricky.
First of all save all your date-time in Utc time. Why? because utc time never follows daylight saving.
Now calculate the local time by converting it to the desired timezone see this link http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=593

Detail overview can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.currenttimezone.aspx